# Removing elements from ArrayList in ascending order

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to remove the elements in the ArrayList in ascending order. I have it down for descending order, but can't figure it out the other way.

I've tried:

```
for (int r = 0; r < s.size(); r++)
```

but it only shows the original elements and the elements minus the element indexed at 0.

So far I have:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList <String> s = new ArrayList<> (4); 
        s.add("A");
        s.add("B");
        s.add("C");
        s.add("D");

        //removes elements in descending order 
        for(int r = s.size()-1; r >=0; r--){
            System.out.println(s);
            s.remove(r);        
        } 

        System.out.println(s.size());

    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: If ascending is from `0` to `size`, step `1` then descending is from `size` to `0`, step `-1`.

Comment: Use an `Iterator`. **NEVER** do what you're doing.

Comment: weird, I'd expect B and D to remain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
        ArrayList <String> s = new ArrayList<String> (4); 
    s.add("A");
    s.add("B");
    s.add("C");
    s.add("D");

    //reverse the arraylist
    Collections.sort(s ,Collections.reverseOrder());
    Iterator<String> i = s.iterator();

    while(i.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(i.next());
        i.remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an `Iterator` you can safely remove items starting from the beginning.

```
for(Iterator<String> i = s.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
  i.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove elements in ascending order, you need to always remove the *first* element, which is always element `0`:

```
while (s.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println(s);
    s.remove(0);
}
```